# Open up a pop-up window, select an item and go back to main window in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Inside a page called `Program edit`, there will be a button named `Select image` and as it is clicked, a Pop-up window will open which shows list of images. After selecting an image from the list and click to the `Add` button, pop-up will close up and selected pictures ID will be passed to main window. It should be available to use at program's params after closing image list popup.

Here is the scenario I would like to have.

Which way should I follow while doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learnt that I can do it via JavaScript and AJAX. Similar to this: http://snipplr.com/view/7461/get-selected-value/

Answer (score 1):

You need a version of [`responds_to_parent`](https://github.com/itkin/respond_to_parent) rails plugin. That can do the trick.

Comment: Uhmm.. Github read me was not so clear to me. Can you explain a little more or give me more resources please?

Comment: Look for `responds_to_parent` examples on the web. It is a stuff you want, let's you to connect the popup with the "parent" window.